# Trying to get property of non-object in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm having this error with a @foreach in a blade view:
**Trying to get property of non-object**

This is the model used in the controller

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Categorias extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categorias';
    protected $fillable = ['categoria'];
    protected $guarded = ['id_categoria'];
}
```

This is the part involved in my controller

```
use App\Categorias;

...

public function create()
{
    $category = Categorias::pluck('categoria','id_categoria');

    return view('convocatorias.create',compact('category'));
}
```

This what i have in my convocatorias.create (blade)

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('category') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="selectbasic">Categoría</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <select id="category" class="form-control input-lg" name="category" value="{{ old('category') }}">
          <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
          @foreach($category as $cat)
              <option value="{{$cat->id_categoria}}">{{$cat->categoria}}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
      @if ($errors->has('category'))
          <span class="help-block">
              <strong>{{ $errors->first('category') }}</strong>
          </span>
      @endif
    </div>
```

If i do a **{{ dd($category) }}** in the view it returns:

```
Collection {#339 ▼
#items: array:2 [▼
1 => "musicians wanted"
2 => "musicians offered"
 ]
}
```

Am i missing something? (laravel 5.4)

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
$category = Categorias::pluck('categoria','id_categoria');
```

to

```
$category = Categorias::get(['categoria','id_categoria']);
```

Now i can use this foreach,

```
@foreach($category as $cat)
<option value="{{$cat->id_categoria}}">{{$cat->categoria}}</option>
@endforeach
```